# How to pass Parameter through Pages in windows store app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I am making a **windows store application**, I need to navigate from a GridView called **categories** to another GridView Called **Items**, Each Category has its own items.

So by using **databinding**, I should have one class of categories and one to items, and *then call the specific function of tricks according to the selection of the user of specific Category.*

How to pass the selection of the user from `categories.xaml.cs` to `items.xaml.cs`? I want the selection of the user to be in a variable to be used in `item.cs`.

I tried to override `OnNavigateTo` but I failed to.

Thanks for all of you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a string variable called selectedItem at categories.xaml.cs to hold the name of the item selected at gridview. To send the value of selectedItem, you should write the following line of code in OnNavigatedFrom method at categories.xaml.cs.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(items), selectedItem);
```

To get the value of selectedItem, you should write the following code in navigationHelper_LoadState method at items.xaml.cs.

```
//you can change the name of the variable below
string selectedItem=e.NavigationParameter as string;
```

You can find more detail [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx). Hope that helps.

Comment: that's exactly what i need but please I have made in the `category.xaml`          `IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" ` , and in the class i send the `ItemClickEventArgs e`   

like this    

`private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CategoryPage),e.ClickedItem);
        }` , `
 
it must be passed to this function in item class like this         clickeditem(ItemClickEventArgs Args)
` , 

how could i call this function in the constructor ??

Comment: @EslamHamed Maybe you can make an instance of item class at app.xaml.cs so that at every page you can use that instance and its variables. And by this means you can call functions in item class. I can help you more if you provide some code related to classes and method you have mentioned about.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's recommended to only pass simple built-in types as a parameter - like int or string. That way `Frame.Get/SetNavigationState()` can be used on suspend/resume to store and rehydrate the navigation history of the `Frame`.

Also note that you can't get the navigation parameter in a page constructor - you need to wait for `OnNavigatedTo()` override or `Page.NavigatedTo` event to retrieve it. You could pass the parameter through some service of your own and then get it in the page constructor but you'd get into special cases (back/forward navigation, rehydration) where you would need to put some effort to reimplement the functionality.